# AppBundler App doesn't stop hopping in Dock

Tags: macos, jar, dock, app-bundle

I use AppBundler vers 1.0 for bundling my jar file to a OSX App.
My application does not have any UI and I think this is the reason why my problem occurs:
When starting the app the icon will hop on the dock just like any other app would do, but it won't stop. After a long time it will stop, but I still find it a little annoying since it looks to the user as if there is a problem starting the app.
I tried to play around with the info.plist file (e.g. LSBackgroungOnly key), but that does not solve my problem.
Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: if you open the "Console.app" application in "`/Application/Utilities`", does it give you any hints as to any errors or warnings happening while you are launching your app?

Comment: No, it does not show anything related to my app.